# python popen special characters not parsing file

Tags: python, popen, mediainfo

I am having issues with non ASCII characters.

I am using python 2.7.3

```
python -V
Python 2.7.3
```

I installed http://pymediainfo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

via

```
easy_install pymediainfo
```

imported as below

```
from pymediainfo import MediaInfo

media_info = MediaInfo.parse(os.path.join(path, to, file))
```

using this with ascii characters is fine

for debugging I printed the 'command' from:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymediainfo-1.3.5-py2.7.egg/pymediainfo/__init__.py
```

the class that 'runs' the mediainfo command in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymediainfo-1.3.5-py2.7.egg/pymediainfo/**init**.py

```
ENV_DICT = {
    "PATH": "/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin/",
    "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "/usr/local/lib/:/usr/lib/"}

@staticmethod
def parse(filename, environment=ENV_DICT):
    command = ["mediainfo", "-f", "--Output=XML", filename]        
    print command
    print repr(command)
    fileno_out, fname_out = mkstemp(suffix=".xml", prefix="media-")
    fileno_err, fname_err = mkstemp(suffix=".err", prefix="media-")
    fp_out = os.fdopen(fileno_out, 'r+b')
    fp_err = os.fdopen(fileno_err, 'r+b')
    p = Popen(command, stdout=fp_out, stderr=fp_err, env=environment)
    p.wait()
    fp_out.seek(0)
    xml_dom = MediaInfo.parse_xml_data_into_dom(fp_out.read())
    fp_out.close()
    fp_err.close()
    return MediaInfo(xml_dom)
```

both print and print repr() display:

```
['mediainfo', '-f', '--Output=XML', "/mnt/path/Long 73\xc2\xb0 58' W.avi"]
```

the filename is:

```
Long 73° 58' W.avi
```

Looking at a UTF-8 table \xc2\xb0 corresponds to °

I am aware this might just be just the console not interpreting the encoding as it should but the output of mediainfo is just

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Mediainfo version="0.7.58">
</Mediainfo>
```

which means "file not found"

```
os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, to, file))
```

returns true for these files

and in bash using

```
mediainfo -f --Output=XML "/path/to/file"
```

works

i have goggled and searched around and cannot see the answer.

Any ideas?

Thanks

UPDATE

I used this new test script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import os
import subprocess as sub
root = "/mnt/path"
    for rootfldr in sorted(os.listdir(root)):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, rootfldr)):
            command = ['mediainfo', '-f', '--Output=XML', rootfldr]
            aa = sub.Popen(command, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE, stdin=sub.PIPE)
            result = aa.communicate()[0]
            print rootfldr
            print result
```

And the results were fine (some of then had non ASCII chars).

I then decided to change (from the pymedinfo parse function):

```
p = Popen(command, stdout=fp_out, stderr=fp_err, env=environment)
```

to

```
p = Popen(command, stdout=fp_out, stderr=fp_err)
```

and the problem was solved

I am guessing that something is missing and or wrong from

```
ENV_DICT = {
    "PATH": "/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin/",
    "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "/usr/local/lib/:/usr/lib/"}
```

Comment: Could you provide a [*complete minimal code example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that would print `Lat 40\xc2\xb0 47' N`? Do you understand the difference between `print repr(o)` and `print o`?

Comment: I have added the function code, I hope this is more understandable now

Comment: You don't need to post `mediainfo` code. Please, read the link from my previous comment. Post the code that other people can run and confirm the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command looks ok. The filename is passed as a bytestring that contains text encoded using utf-8. If your filesystem uses utf-8 then it is correct filename:

```
>>> print "/mnt/path/Long 73\xc2\xb0 58' W.avi".decode('utf-8')
/mnt/path/Long 73° 58' W.avi
```

It might be a bug in [`pymediainfo`](https://github.com/paltman/pymediainfo/issues). Try passing the `environment` argument explicitely as a workaround e.g., `environment=os.environ`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I did not see your comment update before I found the issue with the enviroment. environment=os.environ does work.

Comment: looking at the github version https://github.com/paltman/pymediainfo this is exactly what the dev has done. ENV=os.environ